# How can I get the URL for a controller method in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to avoid duplicating the URL patterns in my application. Currently I have them as annotations at the controller or its methods and I have a service that "knows" the patterns and can generate URLs for resources.

So the problem is not to get the actual URL for a given request but to generate URLs for resources that can be passed to the client without hardcoding the pattern at several places in the application.

I know the Play framework  (Scala/Java) and its "reverse routes". Is there something like that in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: You mean something like this: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetFullUrl(Request)`?

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak, no, I updated the question to make it clear what I mean.

Comment: Perhaps the Action function in this [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper) will work.